# What is a classy, effective way to label a kitchen sink's disposal switch?

Tags: labels, toggle

It bothers me that in-sink food waste disposals usually have an on-off switch that looks identical to a light switch and is often within a set of light switches sharing a single wall plate.

How could I label the disposal's switch in an elegant way that:

- warns *everyone* not to flip the switch (even people who don't know what a disposal is)
- lets people (who know what a disposal is) know that this switch controls the disposal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty impressed with these pictorial labels: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/307982546/switchid-know-which-switch-is-which/description

And for switches like a disposal (which involve a safety concern), I might also add a cover / guard like this: http://www.thingiverse.com/make:13815

Comment: At least as important as any other feature would be to require a spring-loaded "dead-man" switch that shuts off the motor when the switch is released.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for a simple colour differentiation. Anything other than white is clearly not a light switch. People generally understand that a [Big Red Switch](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/2158/big-red-switch-brs) should not be used unless you know what it's for. And this kind of switch is easily purchased.[image: red switch]

Comment: Depending where you live, a switch like that means turning the water heater on, so after pressing it, you expect to have water on the closest sink or shower.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest impact would be using a completely different switch style, one that says "I control heavy, violent machinery, not a little light bulb".

A big, round spring-loaded momentary-on switch with a safety cover and an icon indicating something being hacked to bits (not unlike the standard safety icons for "corrosive", "sharp", etc) would do the job.

Comment: I like it!  Good idea!